# How to make a hexagon tiling?

Tags: graphics, polygons, resourcefunction

I want to make a hexagonal tiling using random colors for each tile. And I am trying make a readable way of doing it.

Here is how to make a hexagonal tiling with a random color (specifically on the blue or pink spectrums):

```
hexes2 = Keys[
   ResourceFunction["HextileBins"][
    Flatten[Table[{x, y}, {x, 0, 12}, {y, 0, 12}], 1], 2]];
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Blue], FaceForm[RandomColor[]], hexes2}]
```

But I want to use these prior commands:

```
PinkSpectrum =Table[(1 - t) *{255,0,127} + t*{255, 255, 255},{t,0,1,.0001}];
BlueSpectrum = Table[(1 - t) *{0, 0, 255}+ t*{255, 255, 255},{t,0,1,.0001}];

Table[Graphics[{RGBColor[RandomChoice[Join[BlueSpectrum, PinkSpectrum]]/255], RegularPolygon[.5,6]}],{n,1,20}]
```

to make a hexagonal tiling where each tile has a random color. So the entire tiling is not the same color. I do not care if like colors are adjacent or not.

Comment: Have a look at [`ResourceFunction["HextileBins"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/HextileBins) in the application section. You could do something like:
`hexes = Keys@ResourceFunction["HextileBins"][
    Flatten[Table[{x, y}, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 5}], 1], 2];
Graphics[Riffle[RandomColor[Length[hexes]], hexes]]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you replace your final line with:

```
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Blue], FaceForm[RandomColor[]], hexes2[[#]]} 
          & /@ Range[Length[hexes2]]]
```

you get different colors for each hex. The problem with your version is that Graphics sees {Edgeform, FaceForm, all 56 hexes}. The version here sees {Edgeform, FaceForm, hex #1}, {Edgeform, FaceForm, hex #2}, {Edgeform, FaceForm, hex #3}... etc.

To constrain the randomness of the color using your Pink and Blue spectrum commands, change this to:

```
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Blue], 
          FaceForm[RGBColor[RandomChoice[Join[BlueSpectrum, PinkSpectrum]]/255]], 
               hexes2[[#]]} & /@ Range[Length[hexes2]]]
```

[image]